# Interfacing existing C++ code with flex

Tags: c++, apache-flex, flex4, adobe, air

I have existing video streaming application which is based client server technlogy.
Existing system is as follows There is data center, client application and gateway. camera is connected with gateway and gateway is connected with data center.client request video to data center and datacenter get it from gateway.

Now we want to use p2p technology here and want to have direct communication between gateway and client.we want to use RTMFP .for client we can use flex, but the existing gtateway code and business logic is written on c++.

Is there any way around to call c++ code from flex.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey, 
Yes this is pretty much possible with flex 4,(ie. only if you are using a desktop application).From a web based swf, running in a browser you cannot start running a C++ code.

I am assuming that you are developing a desktop app.To call a c++ code , you would need to do the things mentioned in the following example link.It is pretty straightforward.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html

Or, incase you have access to the C++ code, then you can use a few already built classes which allow C++/Flex interaction.
http://anirudhs.chaosnet.org/blog/2008.03.13.html

Comment: Thanks Neeraj.To have communication between two peer i.e flex client and gateway i will be using cirrus server.To access cirrus server client need to be developped using flex sdk since my existing gateway code is on c++ i need to have some mechanism to embed flex code in c++ code so that it can interact with cirrus server and and other peer i.e flex client and based on interaction it should interact with c++ code to strean the video to client.
So I wanted how can have communication between flex code  and c++  code can be done.

Comment: Hi Chris,Please look at http://anirudhs.chaosnet.org/blog/2008.03.13.html.It has a detailed explanation with codes and download details for Flex c++ bridge.I am pretty sure that this can help you.

Comment: Thanks Neeraj I have gone through It seems it is for windows platform not for linux.